# WordPress Conditional Post Creation

Tags: wordpress, function

I want this plugin to only create the post with title "Test Post" if it doesn't already exist. For some reason it always creates the post when I activate the plugin. Seems `get_page_by_title('Test Post')` is always false even after the post has been created. Can someone please explain why?

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Create Test Post */


function create_post(){

    if(get_page_by_title('Test Post')){
        return;
    }

    $my_post = array(
        'post_title' => 'Test Post',
        'post_content' => 'This is a test post',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    wp_insert_post($my_post);

} // end create_post

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, create_post);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function get_page_by_title() can only be used on pages, not posts without setting the post type argument.

This will set the appropriate argument for that function. If 'post' is not working try using 'posts'.

The full documentation for this function is found here.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/

```
function create_post(){

$prev_post = get_page_by_title('Test Post', 'OBJECT', 'post');

if ($prev_post != NULL) {
 $prev_post_status = get_post_status( $prev_post->ID );
}

if (!isset($prev_post_status) || !in_array($prev_post_status, array('trash', 'published')) ) {

$my_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'Test Post',
    'post_content' => 'This is a test post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);

wp_insert_post($my_post);

}

} // end create_post

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, create_post);
```

Comment: This seems to work, except if the post exists in the bin, it counts as existing by this approach. Any way to prevent that behavior?

Comment: Yes let me cook it up, ill have an edit for you shortly.

Comment: Try that on for size.

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas. My Brain is frazzled now but I'll test it tomorrow. I'm surprised, I would have thought this would be a fairly common plugin development task and have a simpler solution built in.